# Java & MySQL connection frustration

Tags: java, mysql

I am connecting Java & MySQL.  I have been following [a video series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Em-AhbqVe48), and now I am stuck...completely.

I have done all that the video has said to do in installing MySQL JDBC. However, when I try to access MySQL in (my Mac) Terminal by typing "mysql5 -u mysqladm -p", it simply comes back at me with the message "command not found".

So I'm pretty confused right now as to why this is happening as this is what it typed in during the tutorial and it works, remarkably, on the spot for him.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is mysql installed locally as well as `mysql\bin` on your PATH?

Comment: Do you have mysql server installed also? Not only JDBC driver.

Comment: @Reimeus How do I found out? Juniperi; I have simply done what it says to do at the start of the tutorial, is there more to it?  So sorry, first time trying to do this and getting frustrated :/

Comment: If you have mysql5 installed, can you check to see if it's in your shell path?

Comment: @kuriouscoder How do I do this?

Comment: @user1907323 in that video he only downloads JDBC driver. You need to install server too if it is not installed.

Comment: This problem has nothing at all to do with Java or JDBC, but instead the installation of MYSQL.  Nobody can help you without knowing what platform you are attempting to run MYSQL under, and how you installed it.

Comment: @user1907323 if you are in *NIX, try echo $PATH and see if the binary is one of the referenced paths.

Comment: @juniperi I have now downloaded MySQL (d'oh, missed that part!) where am I supposed to put the folder/document(s)?

Comment: JDBC has nothing to do with mysqladmin.

Comment: @user1907323 search for the tutorial, howto install mysql in osx

Comment: Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/macosx-installation.html .  Come back when you are done.

Comment: @BaileyS I apologise for my misunderstanding but I am still completely confused.  I NOW have installed MySQL as well, steps forwards have been taken.  I have run the installation program and MySQL is running, the pane has been installed etc.  But Terminal still says: "-bash: mysql: command not found"  Any ideas?  MySQL is running, using the methodology below just as a note.

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL` is probably not in your path. Do the following from Terminal:

To determine if mysql is running:

```
ps aux | grep mysql | grep -v grep
```

To find where mysql lives:

```
sudo find / -name mysql
```

The above command may give you a bunch of output. For instance:

```
/usr/local/mysql
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.1-m11-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysql
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.1-m11-osx10.7-x86_64/data/mysql
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.1-m11-osx10.7-x86_64/include/mysql
```

In this case, you're looking for the second one (`bin`). Go to that directory and try `./mysql`

To verify this is not in your [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), do this:

```
echo $PATH
```

To add it to your path:

```
export PATH = $PATH:<whatever path to your installation>
```

Comment: When I type sudo find / -name mysql it tells me "find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory" & "find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory" & "/private/etc/raddb/sql/mysql"...What do I do?

Comment: What you do is `>>install<<` mysql.  If `find` cannot find the `mysql` command then you have not installed it.  If it can find it but running `mysql` says "command not found" then, your PATH is wrong.  These are basic sysadmin issues (not programming issues) and OFF TOPIC for StackExchange.